# how to add button in header to open popover in ion-view ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, popover

I have to create popover in an ion-view page. I try this HTML code :

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
 <div class="buttons">
  <button class="button button-icon ion-more" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
  </button>
  </div>
<ion-content >
</ion-content >
</ion-view>
```

But i didn't get the button in the header page.
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button won't show up unless included in `ion-header`, `ion-nav-buttons`, `ion-content`. You can use the below to add the button to the header:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button class="button button-icon ion-more" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Also make sure `popover` is present on your scope